# argument 1 string to System.Windows.Forms.iwin32window

Tags: c#

I'm Newbie in Visual Studio.
I was getting an error about this code.

```
private void metroLink1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (metroTextBox1.Text=="admin" || metroTextBox2.Text=="123")
    {
        Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();

        settingsForm.Show();
    } 
    else
    {
        MetroMessageBox.Show("Invaild Username or Password", "Error!");
    }
}
```

The error message coming from the `MetroMessageBox.Show("Invaild Username or Password", "Error");`

Comment: What error message are you getting? also, I guess you mean `&&` instead of `||` in your if.

Comment: error message coming from last line of the code -->MetroMessageBox.Show("Invaild Username or Password", "Error"); <--

Comment: you're missing the owner of window in first parameter of `Show()` call. Try pass `this`: `MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Invaild Username or Password", "Error!")`

Comment: @Jack Thanks for helping. It works yay!

Comment: Glad for help. I'll post it as answer so you can accept and we close this thread

Comment: ok thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the owner of window in first parameter of `Show()` call. Try pass `this` (or null, if you don't want to provide an owner Window):

```
MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Invaild Username or Password", "Error!");
```